# Django naturaltime tag

Tags: django, templates, humanize

I want to receive time difference,so I have added 'django.contrib.humanize' to Installed Apps, and '{% load humanize %}' to my template, and use it in as below:

```
{% for notification in request.session.notifications %}
       <li> <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
            <div class="media-object">
                 <img data-src="holder.js/50x50?bg=cccccc" class="img-circle" alt="50x50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="{% static 'img/profile.png' %}" data-holder-rendered="true">
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="media-body">
             <strong class="notification-title"><a href="#">{{ notification.fields.actor_object_id }} {{ notification.fields.verb }} {{ notification.fields.target_object_id }}</a></strong>
             <div class="notification-meta">
                  <small class="timestamp">{{ notification.fields.timestamp|naturaltime }}</small>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
       </li>
{% endfor %}
```

but result is same again: 2017-01-18T10:59:11Z

Comment: What type of field is `timestamp`?

Comment: It is DateTimeField

Comment: Is there any inheritance involved? where do you load humanize exactly?

Comment: you can use timesince filter. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

Comment: I am using Django-notification, I looked at GitHub, and they use timezone.now for timestamp, but when I create object I use DateTime.now, I'm assuming it causes problem.

Comment: `naturaltime` works on DateTime objects, so that isn't the problem... But are you sure `timestamp` is a DateTime object? It looks like the notification is serialized to json when being stored in the session.   

You can debug this by checking the `type()` of the timestamp in your view

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues, you are right, after serialization the type converts to 'dict'

Answer (score 0):

As Resley said, timestamp field converted to dictionary when data serialized to JSON. I created custom tag and used it in my template.

```
from django import template
import dateutil.parser

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='to_date') 
def to_date(value):
    print type(dateutil.parser.parse(value))
    return dateutil.parser.parse(value)
```

then in template, changed the line as following:

```
<small class="timestamp">{{ notification.fields.timestamp|to_date|naturaltime }}</small>
```